# How can I display a populated document in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, mern

I have a kid document in `MongoDB` that contains two populated documents: parent and doctor. And I want to display the parent and the doctor information in the details page of the kid.

this is the service in `nodeJS`:

```js
Router.get('/kids/findKidByID',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query)
    KidModel.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).populate("doctor parent").exec(function (err,u) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'state':'not ok','msg':'err:'+err})
            console.log('err')
        } else {
            res.send(u);
            console.log('succé')
        }
    })
});
```

the kid document:

```js
[{
    "firstname": "Salma",
    "lastname": "Marzouk",
    "doctor": {
        "firstname": "Amira",
        "lastname": "Messaoudi",
        "email": "amira1messaoudi@gmail.com",
    },
    "parent": {
    "firstname": "Radhia",
    "lastname": "Hazgui",
    }
}]

getone() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/admin/kids/findKidByID?_id='+ localStorage.getItem("id"), { method: 'GET' } )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({kid: data})
        })
}
```

but I get an error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not well formatted:

change it to this:

```
[  
   {  
      "firstname":"Salma",
      "lastname":"Marzouk",
      "doctor":{  
         "firstname":"Amira",
         "lastname":"Messaoudi",
         "email":"amira1messaoudi@gmail.com"
      },
      "parent":{  
         "firstname":"Radhia",
         "lastname":"Hazgui"
      }
   }
]
```

and you can use online sites to check your json to see if its valid, sites like [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: the problem is in the service /kids/findKidByID in nodeJS

Comment: no @Yasmine, your problem is in the response getone, you are trying to convert the response into JSON and its not a valid JSON